# Azure Maps - Line Stroke Gradient Color Issues

Tags: azure-maps

I have an application that plots a route on the map. The line on the map shows as a  different color depending on the estimated temperature of the product (this is for food shipments and temperature tracking).

The "hotter" the payload increases during the trip...the line moves from Blue, to Cyan, Green, then to Yellow, and finally to Red. Red signifies the product temperature is going to be too hot for the type of insulation the truck has.

My issue is the line seems to plot and display the colors perfectly. When I zoom in, they start changing. What was once Red...now shows as Yellow. The data that drives the expressions is correct so I can't figure it out.

This simulates a product thats temperature reaches the threshold rather quickly. Notice it starts as blue, goes to cyan, green, yellow...then Red. This looks correct.

[[image: Not Zoomed in1]

[image: Zoomed in]

[image: Zoomed In]

When I zoom in, spots of yellow and orange show up and I can't figure out why. The data behind that point in the line shows of a temperature that should show as "red".

When I do shorter routes...not cross country, I don't seem to have this issue. The longer the line, the more it seems to do it.

My questions are:

Is there a bug out there for this perhaps?
Maybe a better way I could debug this?
Maybe I can do just simple solid lines with no gradient as a work around? I can't find any simple documentation on that.

This is done in angular using the ng-azure-map component/wrapper

**Code to build the line**

```
let tpaTemperatureLine = this.createLineFromPoints(fullRouteCoordinates);
    let tempGradient = this.getTemperatureExpression(this.tpaTemperaturePoints, tpaTemperatureLine);
    this.datasource.add(tpaTemperatureLine); //this adds the line for temperature

    this.temperatureLayer.setOptions({
      strokeWidth: 6,
      offset: 0,
      strokeGradient: tempGradient,
      strokeOpacity: 1
               });
```

**Code to build the expression**

```
getTemperatureExpression(points: Array<TPAPoint>, line) {
      var metric = 'ele';
      let exp: atlas.Expression = [
        'interpolate',  //This will cause the colors from each data point to create a gradient between points.
        ['linear'],
        ['line-progress']
      ];
      let totalLength: number = atlas.math.getLengthOfPath(line);

      let fullStats: any[] = [];
      let progress: number = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        //The line progress value is a value between 0 and 1. 

        let pointTemp = points[i].properties.temp;

        //scales down the dynamic temp ranges to a percentage for using in the expression
        let expressionValue: number = this.getScaledValue(pointTemp, this.minTemp, this.maxTemp, .1, 1);
        let progressVal = Number.parseFloat((progress / totalLength).toFixed(2));

        //Add our business logic on how a data point should be colored
        let colorToPush: string = "blue";
        if (expressionValue > 1) {
          expressionValue = 1;
        }
        if (expressionValue <= .2) {
          colorToPush = "blue";
        } else if (expressionValue > .2 && expressionValue <= .4) {
          colorToPush = "cyan";
        } else if (expressionValue > .4 && expressionValue <= .6) {
          colorToPush = "green";
        } else if (expressionValue > .6 && expressionValue <= .999999999999999) {
          colorToPush = "yellow";
        } else if (expressionValue >= 1) {
          colorToPush = "red";
        }

        //we can only push the same expression value (temperature) to the array. Duplicates cause it not to render at all.
        let existingVal = exp.findIndex(x => x === progressVal);
        if (existingVal == -1) {
          exp.push(progressVal);
          exp.push(colorToPush);
        }

        if (i < points.length - 1) {
          progress += atlas.math.getDistanceTo(points[i].geometry, points[i + 1].geometry);
        }

        //This is just debugging stuff
        let stats: any = {
          location: points[i].geometry.coordinates[1].toString() + "," + points[i].geometry.coordinates[0].toString(),
          temp: pointTemp,
          color: colorToPush,
          rangeVal: expressionValue
        }

        fullStats.push(stats);

      }

      console.log(fullStats);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(fullStats))
      console.log(exp);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(exp))
      //end debugging stuff stuff

      return exp;
```

}

Here is some of the data behind it.

Here is the expression:

```
["interpolate",["linear"],["line-progress"],0,"blue",0.01,"blue",0.02,"cyan",0.03,"green",0.04,"green",0.05,"green",0.06,"yellow",0.07,"yellow",0.08,"red",0.09,"red",0.1,"red",0.12,"red",0.13,"red",0.14,"red",0.15,"red",0.17,"red",0.19,"red",0.2,"red",0.21,"red",0.22,"red",0.23,"red",0.24,"red",0.25,"red",0.26,"red",0.27,"red",0.28,"red",0.29,"red",0.3,"red",0.31,"red",0.32,"red",0.33,"red",0.34,"red",0.35,"red",0.36,"red",0.37,"red",0.38,"red",0.39,"red",0.4,"red",0.41,"red",0.42,"red",0.43,"red",0.44,"red",0.45,"red",0.46,"red",0.47,"red",0.48,"red",0.49,"red",0.5,"red",0.51,"red",0.52,"red",0.53,"red",0.54,"red",0.55,"red",0.56,"red",0.57,"red",0.58,"red",0.59,"red",0.6,"red",0.61,"red",0.62,"red",0.63,"red",0.64,"red",0.67,"red",0.7,"red",0.73,"red",0.76,"red",0.77,"red",0.8,"red",0.82,"red",0.85,"red",0.86,"red",0.87,"red",0.88,"red",0.89,"red",0.9,"red",0.91,"red",0.92,"red",0.93,"red",0.94,"red",0.95,"red",0.96,"red",0.99,"red",1.02,"red",1.03,"red",1.05,"red",1.07,"red",1.1,"red",1.11,"red",1.13,"red",1.14,"red",1.15,"red",1.16,"red",1.17,"red",1.18,"red",1.19,"red",1.2,"red",1.21,"red",1.22,"red",1.23,"red",1.24,"red",1.25,"red",1.26,"red"]
```

Json String based version of the route and its temperature data

```
[{"location":"28.53833,-81.37888","temp":40,"color":"blue","rangeVal":0.1},{"location":"28.54561,-81.60413","temp":40,"color":"blue","rangeVal":0.1},{"location":"28.667414,-81.83738","temp":41,"color":"cyan","rangeVal":0.28},{"location":"28.839512,-82.05292","temp":41,"color":"cyan","rangeVal":0.28},{"location":"29.009373,-82.150734","temp":41,"color":"cyan","rangeVal":0.28},{"location":"29.246859,-82.18869","temp":42,"color":"green","rangeVal":0.45999999999999996},{"location":"29.486704,-82.28898","temp":42,"color":"green","rangeVal":0.45999999999999996},{"location":"29.699348,-82.45395","temp":42,"color":"green","rangeVal":0.45999999999999996},{"location":"29.93319,-82.5615","temp":43,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.64},{"location":"30.143373,-82.66986","temp":43,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.64},{"location":"30.190243,-82.69378","temp":43,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.64},{"location":"30.295221,-82.8891","temp":44,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.82},{"location":"30.350403,-83.0112","temp":44,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.82},{"location":"30.350914,-83.03994","temp":44,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.82},{"location":"30.341864,-83.12313","temp":44,"color":"yellow","rangeVal":0.82},{"location":"30.34191,-83.12595","temp":45,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.34191,-83.12595","temp":45,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.34191,-83.12595","temp":45,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.34191,-83.12595","temp":45,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.39055,-83.33522","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.404686,-83.39556","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.434435,-83.531654","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.469744,-83.82223","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.478333,-84.11456","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.485863,-84.39972","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.640612,-84.979225","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.570793,-84.67445","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.74228,-85.24919","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.748087,-85.54287","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.598526,-84.72895","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.613504,-84.75816","temp":46,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.754803,-85.83644","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.691566,-86.096146","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.73403,-86.36976","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.7157,-86.662285","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.637184,-86.917465","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.513212,-87.15438","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.575111,-87.42315","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.635586,-87.656845","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.657013,-87.90322","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.629948,-88.111244","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.50272,-88.30943","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.438248,-88.57524","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.45423,-88.86633","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.421455,-89.152214","temp":47,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.373177,-89.37559","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.299782,-89.66026","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.370321,-89.95499","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.472866,-90.22121","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47843,-90.23422","temp":48,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.479431,-90.53314","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.471926,-90.84459","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47048,-90.86078","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47048,-90.86078","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47048,-90.86078","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.47048,-90.86078","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.421793,-91.12755","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.441927,-91.21488","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.406834,-91.48409","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.341095,-91.72827","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.265434,-92.000534","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.498615,-92.07214","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.738094,-92.1377","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"30.968996,-92.29014","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"31.176655,-92.46647","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"31.357988,-92.561424","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"31.481264,-92.841705","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"31.650692,-93.08817","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"31.85075,-93.30323","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.02793,-93.53556","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.246872,-93.73512","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.414227,-93.757454","temp":52,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.42056,-93.75975","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.42056,-93.75975","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.42056,-93.75975","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.42056,-93.75975","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.447403,-93.852936","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.47531,-94.077545","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.489487,-94.400604","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.445385,-94.72282","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.435986,-94.97417","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.439423,-95.04297","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.467487,-95.35048","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.48151,-95.505875","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.530006,-95.722435","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.629913,-96.01332","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.69849,-96.26501","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.704365,-96.57859","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.763584,-96.77793","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.76742,-96.886475","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.759686,-97.03317","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.79307,-97.211044","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"32.93371,-97.369316","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.11019,-97.479034","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.247345,-97.60406","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.41473,-97.74304","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.558514,-97.872375","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.68664,-98.07917","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.832924,-98.26168","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.909996,-98.50226","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"33.97077,-98.75836","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.069836,-99.007385","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.07878,-99.02671","temp":53,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.15197,-99.2427","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.24946,-99.4726","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.24946,-99.4726","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.24946,-99.4726","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.24946,-99.4726","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.249924,-99.475044","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.284363,-99.711845","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.34322,-99.91962","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.413418,-100.16705","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.490097,-100.34539","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.64697,-100.478035","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.81077,-100.58899","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.911415,-100.80393","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.99319,-101.01698","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.067215,-101.254555","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.14933,-101.47836","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.19282,-101.74061","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.154343,-103.16079","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.188293,-101.925095","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.161625,-103.46095","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.209763,-102.21675","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.264565,-102.53422","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.15106,-103.77492","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.231884,-102.85303","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.091072,-104.0801","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.037865,-104.394646","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.0343,-104.40293","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.0343,-104.40293","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.0343,-104.40293","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.0343,-104.40293","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.949078,-104.689415","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.977074,-105.001114","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.99258,-105.31431","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.004837,-105.60175","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.00578,-105.92761","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.0792,-106.23138","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.072586,-106.50459","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.067585,-106.78304","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.98968,-107.09433","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.02734,-107.39069","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.063072,-107.52727","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.119537,-107.82238","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.332848,-108.00257","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.400948,-108.24545","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.504013,-108.52149","temp":56,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.52953,-108.74941","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.001095,-109.90127","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.498657,-108.84504","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.331486,-109.076485","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.909725,-110.175896","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.213306,-109.3391","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.10337,-109.61831","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.91035,-110.23547","temp":55,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"34.971245,-110.46776","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.044373,-110.756165","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.113342,-111.05736","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.18021,-111.353035","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.181248,-111.63667","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.25409,-111.91346","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.24706,-112.21283","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.22062,-112.507706","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.2863,-112.80481","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.28681,-113.09366","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.28681,-113.09366","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.28681,-113.09366","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.28681,-113.09366","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.286026,-113.09815","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.19089,-113.374725","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.161537,-113.67472","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.212826,-113.97798","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.271793,-114.16852","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.474457,-114.31409","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.675728,-114.46182","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.871136,-114.60804","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"36.00508,-114.78229","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"35.996254,-114.945145","temp":57,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"36.125393,-115.087585","temp":58,"color":"red","rangeVal":1},{"location":"36.16909,-115.14058","temp":58,"color":"red","rangeVal":1}]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of two things are happening:

When zoomed out the section that is a different color is show small that it...

1. it is hidden by one of your blue pins. Try hiding your pin layer to see if this is the case.
2. that it takes up less than half a pixel of space. As such the gradient is shifting to the more prominent color. If this is the case then I might suggest moving away from gradient and using breaking the line up into individual line segments each with their assigned color.